# R: Extracting the length of characters within a large list

Tags: r, list, string-length

[Large list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFdAM.png)

Is there a possibility to create a variable that captures the length of each chr string within a large list in R?

For example in from the picture above I would like to create a variable that captures that the first chr has a length of 0 the second one a length of 3, the third one a length of 4 and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sapply(hunspell, length)
```

This will apply the `length` function to each element of `hunspell` and return the result as a vector. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4):

The `lengths` command is a built-in that doesn't require applying!

```
lengths(list(c("test", "one"),
         c("testingtwo"),
         c("this", "is", "test", "three")
        ))

[1] 2 1 4
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I was looking for!